# angular Validate can't be done

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I not able to validate my input to the json data whenever i try to compare with json the else block only executed. pls help me to fix this issue.

```
<body ng-app="fileGetting" ng-controller="loadFile">
    <label>Firstname:</label><input type="text" ng-model="placeFile.fname"><br>
    <label>Lastname:</label><input type="text"  ng-model="placeFile.lname"><br>
    <button ng-click="fun()">Submit</button><br>
    <div ng-repeat="x in placeFile">
        <p>{{x.fname}}</p>
    </div>  
    <script>
        angular.module("fileGetting", [])
        .controller("loadFile", function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("exam.json").then(function(response) {
                $scope.placeFile = response.data.names;
                var x = $scope.placeFile;
                $scope.fun = function() {
                    angular.forEach(x, function(value, key) {
                        if ($scope.placeFile.fname == x.key && $scope.placeFile.lname == x.key)
                        {
                            alert("hi ram");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("this is incorrect");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is the Json data:

```
{
    "names":[
              {
                "fname":"Ram",
                "lname":"Chandru"
              },

              {
                "fname":"Chandran",
                "lname":"Krishna"
            },

            {
                "fname":"Jayanth",
                "lname":"Jo"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your json data?

Comment: Hi, well both the fname and the lname will never equal the key...
 
$scope.placeFile.fname == x.key && $scope.placeFile.lname == x.key

key here would equal 'fname' and 'lname'
while 
$scope.placeFile.fname would equal "Ram" or "Chandran" or "Jaynath"

what exactly are you trying to compare?

Comment: Thanks for your reply actually i tried to compare my Html input values to json values. for example my Firstname:Ram and Lastname:Chandru and if i click the submit button it has to alert has to hi ram msg

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly what you are doing the following should work:

First change

```
   <label>Firstname:</label><input type="text" ng-model="placeFile.fname"><br>
   <label>Lastname:</label><input type="text"  ng-model="placeFile.lname"><br>
```

to

```
<label>Firstname:</label><input type="text" ng-model="current.fname"><br>
   <label>Lastname:</label><input type="text"  ng-model="current.lname"><br>
```

code should be:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
      .controller("loadFile", function ($scope, $http) {
          $scope.current = { "fname": "", "lname": "" };
          $scope.placefile = [];
          $http.get("exam.json").then(function (response) {
              $scope.placeFile = response.data.names;
          });
          $scope.fun = function () {
              $scope.placeFile.forEach(function (itm) {
                  if (itm.fname ===  $scope.current.fname 
                  && itm.lname === $scope.current.lname) {
                      alert("Hi Ram");
                  }
                  else {
                      alert("incorrect");
                  }
             });

                };
        });
```

Regards

Magnus

Comment: Thank your for reply magnus you understood well in that pgm but i 've to add the submit button and when i click the submit the button it has to invoke the fun function. And in your program current is not defined in error has occurred. i have tried many ways but not able to fix the error. if you assist me that would be helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i got an answer i would like to thanks Magnus and Simon.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="loadFile">
<label>Firstname:</label><input type="text" ng-model="current.fname"><br>
   <label>Lastname:</label><input type="text"  ng-model="current.lname"><br>
   <button ng-click="fun()">Submit</button><br>

   <script>
  angular.module("myApp", [])
        .controller("loadFile", function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.current = {fname:"", lname:""};
           $http.get("exam.json").then(function(response) {
                $scope.placeFile = response.data.names;
                $scope.fun=function(){
                    $scope.placeFile.forEach(function(itm) {
                        if ($scope.current.fname===itm.fname && $scope.current.lname === itm.lname ) {
                            alert("Hi Ram");
                        }

                        });
                }
        });
        });
      </script>
```